# How do I repeat this animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView which moves when the view is loading.
It'll first go +100 up and then set the a BOOL for completed.

When the BOOL is set to completed, it'll do another animation which puts the UIImageView back to its original position. When my UIImageView then is back at it's original position, it should start the whole thing again. This repeating should last forever! How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
     animations:^

     {
         //move up
         Person.center = CGPointMake(Person.center.x, Person.center.y +100);

     }
                     completion:^(BOOL completed)
     {
         if (completed)
         {
             //completed move up..now move down
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              animations:^
              {
                  Person.center = CGPointMake(Person.center.x, Person.center.y -100);
              }

              ];
         }
     }];
```

Comment: i added answare,please check....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

```
-(void)repeatForever
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^

 {
     //move up
     Person.center = CGPointMake(Person.center.x, Person.center.y +100);

 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed)
 {
     if (completed)
     {
         //completed move up..now move down
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

             Person.center = CGPointMake(Person.center.x, Person.center.y -100);

         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [self repeatForever];
         }];
     }
 }];
```

}

Comment: One more question: When I leave the app and reenter it, the animation stops and my image is just there. How do I change this, so that the animation autorestarts then?

Comment: is this method still called when you reenter in app.add breakpoint and check it....